# Color individual markers on hover in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, marker

I managed to set marker colors for individual markers

```
{
   y: 5,
   marker: {
    fillColor: '#222'
   }
}
```

But onhover it turns into the default color, is it posible to set this value?

I fould the [selectionMarkerFill](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--selectionMarkerFill) option, but this is a child option of chart and has no effect when added in the marker option in my code.

Comment: SelectionMarkerFill is not related to the points, but to the colored area you get when you got zoom enabled (set zoomType to x, y or xy) and drag your mouse over parts of the chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is untested as jsFiddle isn't responding for me right now, but I would take a look at

http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series-states-hover-marker--fillColor

This seems to be the options for markers on hover.

Edit based on janb's comment:

```
 {
    y: 5, 
    marker: { 
        fillColor: '#222', 
        states: { 
            hover: { 
                fillColor: '#222' 
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sondre, this solution worked for me.

{
y: 5,
marker: {
    fillColor: '#222',

    states: {
        hover: {
            fillColor: '#222'
        }
    }
}

Comment: Thanks janb, your comment gave me the solution I was looking for. It should be merged into Sondre's answer.

Comment: @Kar.ma Added it to the answer:)